# Buffer with other publisher - Spring reactor

Tags: spring, project-reactor

Can anyone give an example of how Flux.buffer(Publisher other) works, im unable to make use of the other publisher to split the original flux into multiple lists.

Ex:

```
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("A");
    strings.add("B");
    Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.fromIterable(strings).cache();


    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        strings.add(""+i);
    }
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>(2);
        integers.add(1);
    integers.add(1);
    integers.add(1);

    stringFlux.buffer((a) -> {
        Flux.fromIterable(integers);
    }).subscribe(a -> {
        System.out.println(a);
    });
```

this still prints the original list as the output rather than split it.

Answer (score 0):

`bufferuntil` with a predicate is actually what i was looking for.